# How can I print out current CPU usage and update it in Java Scene Builder (FXML)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm trying to build a CPU monitor tool in scene builder (FXML) and I cannot get it to update the CPU usage in a FXML label. I can get it to print out the cpu usage in the start but that is it. Here is what I have so far.

java file

```
package cpumonitorfxml;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class CPUMonitorFXML extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
    FXMLDocumentController start = new FXMLDocumentController();
     Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100), (ActionEvent) -> {
        double cpu = FXMLDocumentController.getCPUUsage();
        System.out.println("CPU: " + cpu); 


    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(100);
    timeline.play();


    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

FXMLDocument

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="301.0" prefWidth="206.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="cpumonitorfxml.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="229.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="69.0" text="Click Me!" />
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="28.0" layoutY="28.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@gauge.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And FXMLDocumentController

```
package cpumonitorfxml;


import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {


    private Timeline timeline;
    private KeyFrame keyFrame;
    private final double tickTimeInSeconds = 0.01;
    private double secondsElapsed = 0.0;
    private final double angleDeltaPerSeconds = 6.0;


    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }


    public void FXMLDocumentController(){
        timeline.play();
        setupTimer();
    }




       public static double getCPUUsage() {
        OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
        double value = 0;
        for (Method method : operatingSystemMXBean.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
            method.setAccessible(true);
            if (method.getName().startsWith("getSystemCpuLoad")
                    && Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
                try {
                    value = (double) method.invoke(operatingSystemMXBean);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    value = 0;
                }
                return value;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }


    public void setupTimer(){
        if(isRunning()){
            timeline.stop();
        }

        keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(tickTimeInSeconds * 1000), 
                (ActionEvent actionEvent) -> {
                    update();
        });

        timeline = new Timeline(keyFrame);
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    }


        private void update(){
        secondsElapsed += tickTimeInSeconds;

        String str = Double.toString(getCPUUsage());
        label.setText(str);
    }


        public boolean isRunning(){
        if(timeline != null){
            if(timeline.getStatus() == Animation.Status.RUNNING){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

I know that this is pretty rough, I am pretty new to FXML. Obviously there is alot of work to be done, but my main hurdle to get over is creating a timeline(?) that will update the cpu usage as a label. I created a very similar program in JavaFX and had a much easier time with that.

Comment: Do the work in the `Controller` itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are creating confusion by trying to use the `Main` instead of the `Controller` to handle your code.

> Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class JavaFXApplication74 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> Controller

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    Timeline timeline;
    OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        switch(timeline.getStatus())
        {
            case PAUSED:
            case STOPPED:
                timeline.play();
                break;
            case RUNNING:
                timeline.pause();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), (ActionEvent event) -> {            
            label.setText(getCPUUsage().toString());
        }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    }    

    public Double getCPUUsage() {

        double value = 0;
        for (Method method : operatingSystemMXBean.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
            method.setAccessible(true);
            if (method.getName().startsWith("getSystemCpuLoad")
                    && Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
                try {
                     return (double) method.invoke(operatingSystemMXBean);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    value = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

> FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication74.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```